# this.props.onPress(row) is not defined when adding nested array items to the Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got my `React-Native` app running with `Redux` and am trying to add nested array items (products) to my store.

How is the Screen suppose to work?

1. The data from the `productScreen` is passed on from the previous
   screen (selected product)
2. Loop trough the data and find the nested array and display it in a `FlatList`
3. Add/remove selected product to the shopping cart (redux)

Wat works?

1. The data from the `productScreen` is passed on from the previous
   screen (selected product)
2. Loop trough the data and find the nested array and display it in a `FlatList`

What doesn't work is:

3. Add/remove selected product to the shopping cart (redux)

When I navigate to the screen I get the error this.props.onPress(row) is not a function. this.props.onPress(row)is undefined.

I've tried looking online for solutions and on the official [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) web page, but could not find a way to solve this puzzle. Before I nested the array and displayed the products on separate component that was then loaded onto the page, it did use to work.

Anyone know how to add my nested array to the store?

**FlatList**

```
        <FlatList
        style={styles.listContainer}
        data={this.state.filteredProducts}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
```

**RenderItem**

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
    let items = [];
    if( item.products) {
      items = item.products.map(row => {
        return (<View key={row.id} style={styles.products}>
            <View style={styles.iconContainer}> 
                <Icon name={row.icon} color="#DD016B" size={25} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.text}>
                <Text style={styles.name}>
                    {row.name}

                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.price}>
                € {row.price}
                </Text>
            </View>
            {console.log('renderItem',this.state.row)}
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}  onPress={this.props.addItemToCart} >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress(row)} > 
                   <Icon style={styles.button} name="ios-add" color="white" size={25} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}  onPress={this.props.removeItem} >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onPress(row)} > 
                    <Icon style={styles.button} name="ios-remove" color="white" size={25} />
                </TouchableOpacity> 
            </View>
        </View>)

      })
    }
```

**Adding product to the store**

```
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{

    return{
        addItemToCart:(product) => dispatch({
            type:'ADD_TO_CART', payload: product, qty

        }),

        removeItem:(product) => dispatch ({
            type:'REMOVE_FROM_CART' , payload: product, qty
        })  
    }

}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (ProductScreen);
```

**Store.JS**

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import cartItems from '../reducers/carItems';

export default store = createStore(cartItems)
```

**cartItems.JS**

```
const cartItems = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
        // console.log('CarItems.JS', action.payload)
            if (state.some(cartItem => cartItem.id === action.payload.id)) {
                // increase qty if item already exists in cart
                return state.map(cartItem => (
                    cartItem.id === action.payload.id ? { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty + 1 } : cartItem

                    ));

            }
            return [...state, { ...action.payload, qty: 1 }]; // else add the new item to cart

        case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
            return state
                .map(cartItem => (cartItem.id === action.payload.id ? { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty - 1 } : cartItem))
                .filter(cartItem => cartItem.qty > 0);
    }
    return state
} 

export default cartItems
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are passing the result of a function call into the onPress prop of TouchableOpacity.

You might want to try changing
`<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress(row)} >`
to
`<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onPress(row)} >`
as you have done in the second case.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the answer. It seems that it still happens to give the same error when I press the button.

Comment: Sounds like the onPress prop is probably undefined. Did you mean to be calling addItemToCart/removeItem instead? Note that `this.props.onPress` refers to the prop on your screen component, not the View component.